# how to extract pdf signature info in node or react

Tags: reactjs, node.js, pdf, digital-signature, signature

I have a library of signed pdf files that I need to read their signature info in Node.js
like who signed it, when, signature type and ...
and finally render them in a react project (so a library to do the job in react is good either).

many suggested @ninja-labs/verify-pdf
but unfortunately I cant even install the package in project
npm give me errors during installation.

I don't want to sign any file I just need to read their signature info.

Answer (score -2):

You can user `pdf-lib` to read signature information from PDF.

```
const pdfData = fs.readFileSync('your file path')
const pdfDoc = PDFDocumentFactory.load(pdfData)

const signatureFields = pdfDoc.getForm().getFieldsOfType('Sig');

    signatureFields.forEach((field) => {
  const signature = field.getWidgets()[0].getAppearanceStream();
});
```

Comment: I get this error: "pdfDoc.getForm(...).getFieldsOfType is not a function", which version are you using?